# How to list all the installed package in fedora with the time of the installation

Tags: linux, shell, fedora, yum

I can list them use

```bsh
sudo yum list installed
```

but how to make them display when each were installed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As root (or using `sudo`), use the `yum` option `history`.

```
[root@fedora ~]# yum history list
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
ID     | Command line             | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   250 | -y update google-chrome- | 2013-01-30 18:02 | Update         |    1 EE
   249 | -y update                | 2013-01-25 07:11 | Update         |   22   
   248 | -y update                | 2013-01-23 17:56 | Update         |   12   
   247 | -y update                | 2013-01-23 08:41 | Update         |    9 EE
   246 | -y update                | 2013-01-20 21:49 | Update         |    4   
   245 | -x kernel* update        | 2013-01-07 08:11 | Update         |    3
```

You can view the packages and changes for a specific `yum` transaction:

```
[root@fedora ~]# yum history info 250
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Transaction ID : 250
Begin time     : Wed Jan 30 18:02:31 2013
Begin rpmdb    : 1624:34a60f2e27ebe4d959f1473055da42645705b96f
End time       :            18:02:59 2013 (28 seconds)
End rpmdb      : 1624:f4ef7af3a97b1f922f41803ba6b9578a7abe3e71
User           : User <user>
Return-Code    : Success
Command Line   : -y update google-chrome-stable.x86_64
Transaction performed with:
    Installed     rpm-4.9.1.3-1.fc16.x86_64               @updates
    Installed     yum-3.4.3-25.fc16.noarch                @updates
    Installed     yum-metadata-parser-1.1.4-5.fc16.x86_64 @koji-override-0/$releasever
    Installed     yum-presto-0.7.1-1.fc16.noarch          @koji-override-0/$releasever
Packages Altered:
    Updated google-chrome-stable-24.0.1312.56-177594.x86_64 @google-chrome
    Update                       24.0.1312.57-178923.x86_64 @google-chrome
Scriptlet output:
   1 Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  atd.service
```

You can view the history specific packages with:

```
[root@fedora ~]# yum history packages-list yum
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
ID     | Action(s)      | Package                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   148 | Updated        | yum-3.4.3-24.fc16.noarch                           EE
   148 | Update         |     3.4.3-25.fc16.noarch                           EE
    94 | Updated        | yum-3.4.3-23.fc16.noarch                             
    94 | Update         |     3.4.3-24.fc16.noarch                             
    52 | Updated        | yum-3.4.3-7.fc16.noarch                              
    52 | Update         |     3.4.3-23.fc16.noarch                             
     2 | Updated        | yum-3.4.3-5.fc16.noarch                            EE
     2 | Update         |     3.4.3-7.fc16.noarch                            EE
     1 | Install        | yum-3.4.3-5.fc16.noarch
```

`man 8 yum` or `yum help history` will list more options that are possible with the history option.

Comment: _yum list recent_ is also useful

Answer (score 10):

I don't think that `yum` can do that, but `rpm` can:

```
rpm --queryformat="%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}: %{INSTALLTIME:date}\n" -qa
```

will produce a list of entries like:

```
firefox-18.0-1.fc18.x86_64: Mon 14 Jan 2013 13:47:42 GMT
```

Comment: with current versions of rpm you can also get such a list with `rpm -qa --last`

Answer (score 5):

I asked and answered [a similar question on the Fedora Q&A site](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/67231/retrieve-complete-list-of-manually-installed-packages/?answer=67233#post-id-67233).

It turns out that Yum stores its history in an SQLite database in `/var/lib/yum/history`. I was able to concoct this SQL join that shows all the manually installed packages along with their installation date and times.

In my case, I was only interested in the packages I'd manually installed, so I could create a new system with similar tool to those installed on my original system.

The following command prints out every *manually* installed package, the transaction id, date, and `yum` command from history. Note that the database name will be different on your system.

```
$ sudo sqlite3 /var/lib/yum/history/history-2014-12-03.sqlite "select c.tid, datetime(t.timestamp, 'unixepoch'), c.cmdline from trans_cmdline as c join trans_beg as t where c.tid = t.tid"
```

Example output (columns: transaction id, date, command):

```
4|2015-02-21 20:28:03|install mutt wget emacs coreutils
5|2015-02-21 20:28:37|install firefox
6|2015-02-21 20:35:02|install pgp-tools
```

Comment: If you want to get the exact SQLite database file where yum stores its history, run the following command: `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sudo yum history stats | grep -Po '(?<=File {8}: /)(.+)' --color=never`